# Neovim startup message is missing

Tags: ubuntu, neovim

When i give command `nvim` to the terminal. I want my neovim display the message like the picture below.
[image]

But instead, my nvim displays nothing directly.
[image]

Can someone please help me with this trivial problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? It seems to me, that it is a mix of some options and plugins overwriting them, though too many too test.

Comment: yes, i just remove all the plugin and restart all again. and it back to normal

Answer (score 2):

I'd assume that some plugin is removing the startup-screen, at least I've got the same problem like you, but I'm getting my startup-screen back if I open up neovim with `nvim --noplugin`.

Comment: yes, i just remove all the plugin and restart all again. and it back to normal